# Fiddler running in the background fixes HttpPost for access token. Also works in Postman

Tags: .net, oauth, postman, token

I am unable to get an access token in .NET console app. I have written a unit test which fails.

The post however, works from postman, and also in the console app if I have fiddler  running in the background decrypting https requests.

I do not know why fiddler makes it work, but if it is running I get an access token

The errors I get are either 'Database ***** not found in database configuration file' or 'Client_id or Client_secret is invalid'

Code is below:

```
var url = _baseUrl + "token";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

        var grantType = "password";
        var integrated = "N";

        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Deltek.Username"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Deltek.Password"];
        var database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Deltek.DatabaseName"];
        var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Deltek.ClientId"];
        var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Deltek.ClientSecret"];

        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("username", username);
        values.Add("password", password);
        values.Add("grant_type", grantType);
        values.Add("integrated", integrated);
        values.Add("database", database);
        values.Add("client_Id", clientId);
        values.Add("client_secret", clientSecret); // _keyvaultservice.getSecret(keyvault + secretname)

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        request.Content = content;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
       ServicePointManager
            .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DeltekToken>();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, Postman works even without Fiddler running in the background

Comment: This has been reproduced on a colleagues setup by checking in and pulling the latest code. Not sure what that rules out though!